# Dropdown jQuery not performing

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

This script is ran when the user clicks on a dropdown and makes a different selection and then changes the session key called defaultCharacterID and I'm tyring to figure out when it brings up the post request in the console that it says "The action you have requested is not allowed.

PHP:

```
public function changeDefaultCharacter()
{
    if ($this->input->post('defaultCharacterID'))
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata($this->input->post('defaultCharacterID'));
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#charactersDrop').change(function() {
    // POST the changed value to a method in a controller that can accept
    // a parameter and that'll set the session variable for you
        $.post('dashboard/changeDefaultCharacter',
          { defaultCharacterID: this.value },
           'html'
          ); 
    });
});
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#charactersDrop').change(function() {
    // POST the changed value to a method in a controller that can accept
    // a parameter and that'll set the session variable for you
    $.post('dashboard/changeDefaultCharacter',
      { defaultRosterListID: this.value },
      <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(). ':'. 
           $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>
      }
   ,
   'html'
});
});
```

Comment: What version of CI you using ?

Comment: check config file for `csrf_protection` value, make sure its `false`

Comment: That fixed it however why was that creating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `config.php` and make sure that:

```
   $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

THis error cause because of ajax protection, checking session token. You can also set it off temporary for only one controller

```
  $this->config->set_item("csrf_protection",FALSE);
```

**UPDATED**

Or better leave protection `true` and add `csrf token` to your request

```
$.post('dashboard/changeDefaultCharacter',
      {
         defaultCharacterID: this.value, 
        <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(). ':'. 
               $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
        ?>
       }
       ,
       'html'
      );
   ...
```

Comment: suggesting disabling security does not sound like a good approach to me. It's like suggesting of removing doors if there are some issues with the lock

Comment: Okay now do I have the controller function correct. With that code presented like that will it replace the old value?

Comment: So you think it should be working because I can't figure out how to test out if it actually changed or not.